# Shortcode with product catgory counter

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, count

I would like to create a custom shortcode that count individually product-categories in Woocomerce but I haven't found any code on net. I need somethink like:

**[counter product-category="example"]**

Anyone can help me? I've no idea about php :(

```
<?php
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
?>
```

Comment: what do you want ? the numbers of products in a category ? or the number of categories with products ?

Comment: The total products in a category.

Comment: you can retrive the category object with the function [get_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) and then you can have the product count in the argument `count` of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (add it to the theme's main *functions.php* file)

```
add_shortcode( 'products-counter', 'products_counter' );
function products_counter( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( [
        'category' => '',
    ], $atts );

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    if ( is_numeric( $atts['category'] ) ) {
        $cat = get_term( $atts['category'], $taxonomy );
    } else {
        $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], $taxonomy );
    }

    if ( $cat && ! is_wp_error( $cat ) ) {
        return $cat->count;
    }
    return '';
}
```

You can use it like this:

- By specifying the product category **ID**:

`[products-counter category="19"]`

- By specifying the product category **slug**:

`[products-counter category="hoodies"]`

Example:

[image]